# Do I have to be a Bloodrager in order to have Bloodrage Rage Powers?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation

Although is seems like a no-brainer, I still have to ask :)

Looking at [rage powers](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers), it's divided into three categories:

- General Rage Powers
- Totem Rage Powers
- Bloodrage Rage Powers

Just by looking at the rage power page, there is no requirement to have the [Bloodrager hybrid class](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/bloodrager) in order to use the Bloodrage Rage Powers.

Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### On the contrary: You *have* to be a barbarian

Levels in the [Bloodrager](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/bloodrager) does *not gain any Rage Powers at all*.

Blood Rage Powers are a type of Rage Powers that were introduced in the Advanced Class Guide, that allow a Barbarian to mimic some parts of the Bloodline Powers of a Bloodrager. Blood Rage powers are presented in the ACG's *Archetype and Class Features* chapter, under *Barbarian*. The text states (emphasis mine):

> **Any barbarian** meeting the prerequisites can take the following **new rage powers**. Blood rage powers grant powers in a theme. **A barbarian** cannot select from more than one group of blood rage powers. [...]

The major prerequisite for taking blood rage powers that the character is eligible to take rage powers, which in most cases requires them to be a barbarian (or count as a barbarian for the purpose of rage powers).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Does that mean I can't select Lesser Fiend Totem **and** Lesser Abyssal Blood?

Comment: @Steven You can select both. You are limited to a single type of totem and to a single type of blood, but the two do not affect each other.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Mr Lemon's information, there is the Primalist archetype for the Bloodrager, that lets you sub out bloodline powers for rage powers at the same rate a Barbarian would gain them. You do lose access to the Extra Rage Power feat, but all-in-all it is a very strong archetype (hence it being disallowed in Pathfinder Society organized play).

Otherwise though, no, you cannot utilize rage powers during a bloodrage.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately my GM is not using ACG at the moment.